# What kind of function do I need to avoid repeating act in R studio?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data table look like:

```
names --- group ---- events ...
```

The table need to be subset according to the group value (the value is numeric and n= 50+). A working R function is:

```r
Group8 <- subset(Data, Data$group == "8").
```

However, n of the "group" is 50+, to repeat this function again and again, is time consuming and not clear for later use. Can anybody provide a R function to avoid this repeating act?

Comment: You could try `DataList <- split(Data, Data$group)` which will put all of your groups into a list of data frames which you could access like this: `DataList[["8"]]`

Comment: It's almost for sure a bad idea to have 50+ dataframes floating around your environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
DataList <- split(Data, Data$group)
```

This will put all of your groups into a list of data frames which you could access like this:

```
DataList[["8"]]
```

If you really want to have all of these variables in your global environment (which probably isn't a great idea), you can use `assign` inside an `lapply` like this:

```
lapply(names(DataList), function(x) assign(paste0("Group", x), DataList[[x]], globalenv()))
```

Comment: It is indeed a bad idea to have all these dataframes in global environment, however, I still need to export these dataframes. How can I do it without repeating act?

Comment: @starter1128 you can do something like `for(i in seq_along(DataList)) write.csv(DataList[[i]], paste0("Group', i, ".csv"))`

Comment: @ Allan Cameron Thanks, it works very well. After creating the datalist, it is a file contains 50+ dataset, is it possible to use DataList to analysis each dataset? For example, what if I want to know the amount of variable A within each Group and what if I want to calculate the mean of the variable A in each group?

Comment: @starter1128 if you want to carry out some function on each data frame in your list, you use `lapply`. So, for example, if you want to know the number of rows of each data frame you can do `lapply(DataList, nrow)`, or if you want to know the mean of `events` you could do `lapply(DataList, function(x) mean(x$events))`

Comment: @ Allan Cameron some how the mean is not calculated, the output shows the mean = 0. And if I want to know the mean of the variables (for instance column 3--37 of each dataset) based on the character of column 1 of each dataset. Can I put aggregate function in the lapply() ?  
I firt tried for 1 dataset: lapply(Datalist, aggregate(Datalist[["1"]][, 3:37], by = list(Datalist[["1"]]$group), FUN = mean)). A error appears, "Error in match.fun(FUN)" , possible solution?